# i want to redirect email for another page in flutter

Tags: database, flutter, api, dart

i want to redirect email to Forget password page to reset page
**This is my reset password button code**

```dart
    child: ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      String email = emailController.text;
                                      String otp = otpcontroller.text;
                                      String password = userPasswordcontroller.text;
    
                                      **List<UserLogin> res = await LoginController**
                                          .createResentpassword(
                                        email,
                                        password,
                                        otp,
                                      );
    
                                      // if (res[0].userEmail == emailController.text)
                                      Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                          msg: "password change Sucessfully",
                                          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                                          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                          backgroundColor:
                                              Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 87, 156),
                                          textColor: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 12.0);
                                      //else {
                                      Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                          msg: "password not change",
                                          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                                          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                          backgroundColor:
                                              Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 87, 156),
                                          textColor: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 12.0);
                                      // }
    
                                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (_) => ResetPassword()));
    
                                      //
                                      setState(() {
                                        //createdAt,
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: const Text("Change Password"),
                                    style: ButtonStyle(
                                        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 89, 168))),
                                  ))
                            ],
                          ))))));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Passing data forward to the next screen**

*In order to send data to the next screen you do the following things:*

In the `ResetPasswordScreen`, you should create a `constructor` which takes a parameter which is called "email".

```
class ResetPasswordScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String email;
  ResetPasswordScreen({Key key, @required this.email}) : super(key: key);

  ...
```

Then, you should use the `Navigator` in the `ForgotPasswordScreen` to push a route to the `ResetPasswordScreen` widget. You put the data that you want to send as a parameter in its constructor.

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ResetPasswordScreen(email: emailController.text,),
    ));
```